# Админка на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли сделать админку на JavaScript? Есть HTML и CSS. ПК без интернета, то есть PHP отпадает — нужно сделать, чтобы была возможность менять характеристики (данные в HTML) посредством JavaScript. То есть при открытии HTML в браузере должно быть всплывающее окно с полями для заполнения, как только эти данные заполнены, их нужно сохранить и записать в HTML.
Это нужно записывать в кэш через LocalStorage? Или без интернета это нельзя сделать? Есть ли способ менять содержимое HTML файла через браузер (HTML-форму)?

Comment: Можно поставить локальный веб-сервер с php.

Comment: Думал об этом, но все же хотелось бы попробовать на js как то реализовать

Comment: Да, можете использовать localstorage.

Comment: То-есть при отсутсвии интернета данные запишутся в кэш и сохранятся там до их очистки? Просто мне нужно что бы данные при открытии документа один раз записались и были всегда заполнены без необходимости их заполнять повторно.

Comment: Вообще админка подразумевает управление чем-то. Чем вы собрались управлять, оперируя локальными данными?

Comment: смотрите в сторону nodejs

Comment: обычно админка нужна для сайтов, в которых есть хотябы список пользователей. Обычно такая информация хранится в БД. Ладно...рассмотрим ситуацию без сервера...предположим у вас будет файловая БД, тогда все возможно. Но это столько ненужной работы...ps в большинстве компаний, которые заподятся о безопастности данных нет выхода в глобальную сеть (есть но он конкретно бьется). Обычное решение - локальный сервер + vpn. И еще...хранить данные в localStorage вообще бессмыслено(т к нет уверенности в их целостности)

Comment: Спасибо большое, уважаемые "эксперты"... Не важно что подразусмевает админка и для чего она обычно нужнf, мне нужна она для заполнения полей формы, и что бы эти поля сохранялись. Что значит нет уверенности в их целостности?

Comment: @ilyaaa521 любой пользователь в браузере можешь поменять данные в localStorage.